# How to pass more than one value inside a parameter to a dataAdapter Using IN clause on postgres database

Tags: c#, postgresql, webforms, reportviewer

How to pass more than one value inside a parameter to a dataAdapter using an IN clause on postgres database using reportviewer?

Passing only one value in the paramenter to the query , the report is compiled without errors

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["port"] = "SANTOS";
}
```

but when we add more values ​​in the same parameter nothing is found 
ex port = SANTOS , ITAJAI ;

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["port"] = "SANTOS , ITAJAI";

}
```

obviously when I put two values ​​straight into the SQL query I have the corret result ​​returned

```
 WHERE ... AND (fk_lporto IN ('SANTOS', 'ITAJAI')) ... ;
```

[image]

Comment: Would it maybe something like e.InputParameters["ports"] = "'SANTOS','ITAJAI'" to match the query string you executing directly?

Comment: I have the expected result when the values ​​are  directly SQL,
as an example below.

 WHERE        (year = TO_NUMBER('2012', '9999')) AND (fk_month BETWEEN '01' AND '12') AND (fk_lporto IN ('SANTOS', 'ITAJAI')) 

but when I assign the same values ​​to the @port parameter nothing is found, as an example below

 e.InputParameters["port"] = "'SANTOS','ITAJAI'";